# My variable starts with 'undefined' followed by the variable when viewed in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

so I am making a converter from Decimal to Binary using JS and HTML. I'm nearly finished with my task, but my code keeps printing '**undefined**' along with the answer.

For example, if I enter the number 9, I will get an output of:

0bundefined1001

Why is the 'undefined' there, and how do I get rid of it?

```js
// NECESSARY VARIABLES DEFINED
let decimalNum; // User's input
let binaryNum; // (soon) converted decimalNum
let x = 0; // explained in the algorithm 

// THIS FUNCTION CHECKS WHETHER THE USER'S INPUT IS A NATURAL NUMBER
function is_Natural(n) {
  if (typeof n !== 'number')
    return 'Not a number';
  return (n > 0) && (Math.floor(n) === n) && n !== Infinity;
}

// THIS SECTION CONVERTS THE USER'S INPUT TO THE BINARY SYSTEM
document.getElementById("mySubmit").onclick = function() {
  decimalNum = document.getElementById("decimalNum").value; //retrieves the user's input and stores it in the previously defined variable
  decimalNum = Number(decimalNum)
  if (is_Natural(decimalNum) === true) {
    while (true) {
      if (decimalNum < 2 ** x) {
        x = x - 1 // For it to let the left-most value be equal to 1
        break
      } else {
        x = x + 1
      }
    }
    while (true) {
      if (decimalNum >= 2 ** x) {
        binaryNum = binaryNum + '1';
        decimalNum = decimalNum - 2 ** x;
        x = x - 1
      } else {
        binaryNum = binaryNum + '0'
        x = x - 1
      }
      if (x < 0) {
        break
      } else {
        continue
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("binaryNum").textContent = `Here is your number in the Binary system: 0b${binaryNum}`; // replaces the placeholder
}
```

```html
<h1> Converter from Decimal to Binary</h1>
<label for="decimalNum" title="A positive whole number (1, 2, 3, etc.), excluding 0 and inifinity."> Decimal (natural number) </div>: </label>
<input id="decimalNum" type="number">
<button id="mySubmit"> Submit </button>
<p id="binaryNum"> </p>
<!-- Placeholder for the printed form in the Binary system.-->
<i> Please note that the <b>0b</b> index in the Binary number is a prefix to indicate its system.</i>
```

Comment: You have not given the variable any initial value, so of course `binaryNum = binaryNum + '1';` results in `undefined1` the first time this runs, because the _read access_ to the `binaryNum` on the right side of the equal sign can't return anything other than `undefined`. Just initialize the variable with an empty string: `let binaryNum = '';`

Comment: Here is a more elegant version: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/setdk01L/

Comment: See also [Number.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) eg `decimalNum.toString(2)`

Answer (score 1):

the binaryNum variable without initializing it with an empty string. as an output it starts with the undefined (the default value for an uninitialized variable in JavaScript for let,var).

Comment: just add let binaryNum = ''; on the declaration time.

Comment: I changed it and it did the trick. Thank you! I'm new to JavaScript, so it's a newbie mistake. :/ I will mark your answer as 'accepted' as soon as I can (there is a 15 minutes cooldown after making a post). Have a nice day ^^

Answer (score 0):

'binaryNum' requires a default value